# How do people create website where they have a screen shot inside a phone image?

Tags: mobile, design

I am trying to work on my website, which is for a mobile application. While I can put an image of my app screenshot on my website, what I am not sure how to do is to create a shiny device image like most websites which promote apps.

For example, `path.com` is a popular app. On their website, on the right side, is an image of a device and inside the device is a screen shot.  How could I make that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are done by taking a screen shot of your app, and then placing that inside of a device PSD (Photoshop file) template which you can find by just Googling for "device name PSD" - for instance [here](http://www.teehanlax.com/tools/iphone) is a iPhone 5 PSD template.

Comment: i would also recommend this question is moved to the graphic design stack exchange site, by an admin

Comment: moving this question makes sense. For some reason I had the impression that that site was being phased out.

Comment: i dont think so, i think its just in beta

Answer (score 2):

[Placeit](http://placeit.breezi.com/) will do it for you. Pretty slick. And free.

You could also pay a designer about $5 to insert a screen shot (that's what we did).

Answer (score 1):

Though the PSD mock-up is the norm, I've also loaded a screenshot of an app I'm developing onto my phone and displayed it fullscreen. Then I take a picture of it. This to me looks the most realistic as you can even see the pixels on the phone.

Comment: Unless one has access to a green screen and good lightning such a picture might end up looking bad.